# img width inside an absolutely positioned parent element

Tags: html, css

I have an image inside aboslute div. I want image to be responsive and max width 100% (its own width).

With following code this work well, however ONLY if I add width:100% on '.item'. I dont want that because it blocks any potential content behind (z-index or pointer-events are not accepted). I cannot use flex on wrap because I have multiple children that need to be aligned separately.

If I remove width:100% on '.item', then as I resize and shrink the window down, '.item' shrinks down and makes image smaller than it can acually be. If there a css solution to this?

```css
.wrap {

}

.item {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;/* this makes item width 100% of parent, I dont want that. If I remove it, image size gets smaller as window shrinks */
  max-width: 100%;
}

.item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: so use min width, or do display flex on wrapper

Comment: I cannot use flex on wrap because I have multiple children that need to be aligned separately. Min-width 100% on wrap also makes wrap 100% pr parent which I dont want.

Comment: create another wrapper for the img then, or its siblings

Comment: Is the `.item` wrapper needed for anything else here? Because if not, remove it, and directly position the image instead, and you should have what you want ...?

Comment: Yes,  I need (at least one more to wrap image and some buttons)

Comment: @SteveTomlin - I dont se how another wrapper changes anything. I need absolute div holding image and not larger than image. It seems that css translate is causing div to shrink, becuase without translate and just top:0, left:0, div behaves as intended.

Comment: To be honest I'm just suggesting ideas. Since I cannot see what your intention is with obvious diagrams I'm not sure what you want to do

Comment: Well exactly what the demo shows (without flex).

Comment: Image is responsive, isnt it? Its just that this translate is making it smaller than it can actualy be in available space. (unless item has width 100%)

Answer (score 1):

Use `max-width: 100vw;` on the image and remove all the percentage values

```css
.wrap {

}

.item {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}

.item img {
  max-width: 100vw;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Or use a different way to center the image:

```css
.wrap {

}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
}

.item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
  </div>

</div>
```